# time difference between two time pickers using js

Tags: javascript, timepicker

Im using two time pickers and it's displaying the time difference but i want the time difference in text box.
My code is as follows:

```
Start time: <input type="text" id="diff_time1" value=""><br>
End time: <input type="text" id="diff_time2" value=""><br>
<div id="diff_output">Time Difference
<input type='text' name='Time_diff'/></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng_all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ng.ready( function() {
    ng.ready(function(){
        var tmpkr1 = new ng.TimePicker({
            input: 'diff_time1',
            events: {
                onSelect: calc_diff,
                onUnselect: calc_diff
            }
        });
        var tmpkr2 = new ng.TimePicker({
            input: 'diff_time2',
            events: {
                onSelect: calc_diff,
                onUnselect: calc_diff
            }
        });

        function calc_diff(){
            // getting the selected time values
            // value is a timestamp of the selected date
            // or null
            var tm1 = tmpkr1.p.value;
            var tm2 = tmpkr2.p.value;

            if ((!ng.defined(tm1)) || (!ng.defined(tm2))) {
                ng.get('diff_output').innerHTML = '';
                return;
            }

            var dif = Math.abs(tm1 - tm2); // difference in milliseconds
            var seconds = Math.round(dif/1000);
            var minutes = 0, hours = 0;
            if (seconds > 60) {
                minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                seconds = seconds - (minutes * 60);
            }
            if (minutes > 60){
                hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                minutes = minutes - (hours * 60);    
            }

            var output = '';
            if (hours > 0) output = hours +' hours, ';
            if ((hours > 0) || (minutes > 0)) output += minutes+' minutes and ';
            output += seconds + ' seconds';

            ng.get('diff_output').innerHTML = output;
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to compare the time difference which i give it manually with which we got from the timepicker. If the time difference is equal then i transfer the flow to next page and the time which i enter is in Integer format

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what you want to do.

Can you describe the task?

As I understood you have two timepickers, right?

The User picks two times on your webpage and then what?

You want to calculate the time difference between these two times?

Then you want to compare this evaluated time difference with some constant timestamp and if they are equal, you want to transfer the flow to the next page, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var secondsPerMinute = 60;
var minutesPerHour = 60;
function convertSecondsToHHMMSS(intSecondsToConvert) {
    var hours = convertHours(intSecondsToConvert);
    var minutes = getRemainingMinutes(intSecondsToConvert);
    minutes = (minutes == 60) ? "00" : minutes;
    var seconds = getRemainingSeconds(intSecondsToConvert);
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}

function convertHours(intSeconds) {
    var minutes = convertMinutes(intSeconds);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / minutesPerHour);
    return hours;
}
function convertMinutes(intSeconds) {
    return Math.floor(intSeconds / secondsPerMinute);
}
function getRemainingSeconds(intTotalSeconds) {
    return (intTotalSeconds % secondsPerMinute);
}
function getRemainingMinutes(intSeconds) {
    var intTotalMinutes = convertMinutes(intSeconds);
    return (intTotalMinutes % minutesPerHour);
}

function HMStoSec1(T) { // h:m:s
    var A = T.split(/\D+/); return (A[0] * 60 + +A[1]) * 60 + +A[2]
}
```

Use below code to handle differences

```
var time2 = HMStoSec1('17:00:00');
var time1 = HMStoSec1('08:00:00');
if(time1 < time2) {
    var diff = (time2 - time1);
    var result = convertSecondsToHHMMSS(diff);
} else {
    var diff = (time1 - time2);
    var result = convertSecondsToHHMMSS(24 * 60 * 60 - diff);
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.